# how to set array multidimential in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

hi can you help me for looping and add array multidimential, because in php it's like easy for create array multi dimention but in javascript i don't know how to make array multidimential but i try like this but error and i don't have any idea

```
  data_array.forEach((element,i) => {
         
            data1[element.produsen_id][element.category_id] = element.data_value
        })
```

i try explain for the excel data

[image]

this json format what i need

```
{"main_report": {
"value": {
  "2": {
    "5": "0",
    "7": "0",
    "3": "13",
    "1": "3",
    "10": "0",
    "9": "4",
    "2": "3",
    "8": "0"
  },
  "3": {
    "2": "3",
    "10": "0",
    "1": "2",
    "5": "0",
    "3": "0",
    "9": "0",
    "8": "7"
  },
  "4": {
    "3": "2",
    "10": "0",
    "1": "2",
    "8": "3",
    "2": "2",
    "5": "0",
    "9": "4",
    "7": "1"
  },
  "5": {
    "5": "0",
    "10": "0"
  },
  "7": {
    "3": "0"
  },
  "8": {
    "1": "4",
    "7": "0",
    "8": "0"
  },
  "9": {
    "9": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "3": "0",
    "7": "1",
    "5": "0"
  },
  "10": {
    "3": "0"
  },
  "11": {
    "7": "0",
    "2": "1",
    "3": "11",
    "9": "3",
    "8": "0",
    "1": "1"
  },
  "13": {
    "5": "0",
    "2": "0",
    "8": "0",
    "10": "5",
    "3": "1",
    "1": "0",
    "9": "0"
  },
  "15": {
    "10": "0"
  },
  "16": {
    "10": "0"
  },
  "17": {
    "10": "0"
  },
  "18": {
    "10": "0"
  },
  "19": {
    "10": "0"
  },
  "1": {
    "2": "4",
    "9": "9",
    "3": "8",
    "7": "5",
    "1": "6",
    "4": "2",
    "5": "2"
  },
  "6": {
    "7": "0",
    "3": "3",
    "2": "1",
    "9": "1",
    "1": "1"
  },
  "20": {
    "1": "4",
    "2": "3",
    "9": "5",
    "3": "13",
    "4": "0",
    "7": "1",
    "10": "0"
  }
}
```

}
}

in php looping like this

```
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
        $return_arr[$value->id_1][$value->id2] = $value->value_data;
    }
```

how to implement in javascript, i will appriciate for your answer thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solutions:**

We are gonna use objects instead of arrays.

Initialize data1 with empty object `data1 = {}` and now:

Solution 1:

```
data_array.forEach((element) => {
  // if data1[element.produsen_id] doesn't exist yet
  if(!data1[element.produsen_id]) {
    data1[element.produsen_id] = {}
  }
  data1[element.produsen_id][element.category_id] = element.data_value
})
```

Solution 2 (alternatively):

```
data_array.forEach((element,i) => { 
  data1[element.produsen_id] = {
    ...(data1[element.produsen_id] || {}),
    [element.category_id]: element.data_value
  } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

These are nested objects you have not multidimensional arrays
**{}** are for objects and **[]** are for arrays

Comment: hallo vojin, can this loop like array multidimentional like i explain in php? or you can explain what shoul i do

Comment: Yes you can but it is a bit more complicated with objects (Key Value pairs). You can get your keys which are actually indexes in your case with let keys = Object.keys(data_array) and then looping object with those like keys.forEach(k=> console.log(data_array[k])). You go by this method in depth because you have nested objects

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error do you get? Maybe this is the solution

```
data_array.forEach((element) => {
  // if data1[element.produsen_id] doesn't exist yet
  if(!data1[element.produsen_id]) {
    data1[element.produsen_id] = []
  }
  data1[element.produsen_id][element.category_id] = element.data_value
})
```

Comment: hi jan i try this but null in result like this `"value": [
  null,
  [
    null,
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    null,
    "0",
    null,
    "0"
  ],
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  [
    null,
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    null,
    null,
    "0",
    "0",
    null,
    "0"
  ],
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  [
    null,
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    "0",
    null,
    null,
    "0",
    null,
    "0"
  ]
]
}`

Comment: Ok. I see. So we need to use objects instead of arrays. Try initializing data1 by empty object like this `data1 = {}` and the same in the snippet I provided `data1[element.produsen_id] = {}`

Comment: oke i try like this `  data_array.forEach((element,i) => {
              data1[element.produsen_id] = {[element.category_id]  : element.data_value}        
            })` but data just show 1 like this `  "value": {
            "1": {
                "2": "0"
            },
            "6": {
                "7": "0"
            },
            "20": {
                "2": "0"
            }
        }`

Comment: i try edit my question the true data

Comment: Yes. Because you override existing values. Have tried my solution? I think it works

Comment: Alternatively you can use this: ```data_array.forEach((element,i) => { 
  data1[element.produsen_id] = {
    ...(data1[element.produsen_id] || {}),
    [element.category_id] : element.data_value
  } 
})```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239376/discussion-between-riyan193-and-jan-krupinski).